# What is the correct way to join these tables?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

```
**itemwhse**

item (primary key)
whse (primary key)
...other fields...


**job**

job (primary key)
suffix (primary key)
item
whse
...other fields...
```

The `job` table stores information about jobs were an item was produced. These items are produced at a certain warehouse, but then they can be transported to another facility for storage. The `itemwhse` table is what holds the inventory amounts and item numbers.

I noticed that I get the correct info either way, but I'd like to know which is correct: inner joining on `item` and `whse` or inner joining on `item` only.

---

Sample Data:

```
**itemwhse**

item        whse        qty
ItemA       BART        1000
ItemA       BEN         1500


**job**

job         suffix      item       whse        qty
foo1        1           ItemA      BART        2500
```

Example Query:

```
select

   j.job
   , j.suffix
   , j.item
   , j.whse
   , i.item
   , i.whse

from

   job as j
   inner join itemwhse as i on j.item = i.item
```

Comment: Look at the PF/FK relations in your ER-diagram.

Comment: Add some sampe table data and the expected result - as formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: @jarlh yup, sorry, I accidentally hit the submit button and it posted the question before I was done.

Comment: why don't u post your query?

Comment: @Hatik I posted it but I think it should be pretty simple to envision without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `item+whse` is a composite primary key then you should join by both of them.

`Itemwhse` is an association table that relates `Item`  to `Warehouse` with multiplicity M:N.

If you join `Job` with `Itemwhse` only by `item`, you get items of certain type in all warehouses, not only in the warehouse in question.